# External extractor '7z' error when extract F/W image use Binwalk

Tags: debian, python, libraries, 7z

Got error when tried to extract compressed F/W image use **Binwalk 2.3.3**:

```
WARNING: Extractor.execute failed to run external extractor '7z e -y '%e'': 'module' object has no attribute 'DEVNULL', '7z e -y '%e'' might not be installed correctly
1578          0x62A           LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 16777216 bytes, missing uncompressed size
```

`p7zip` and `p7zip-full` packages are installed.
How to solve this error?

Debian 9, Python2.7, Binwalk v2.3.3

Comment: You could always try to run it under `strace -fe execve` to see what it tries to execute if anything.

Comment: the `strace` output is not too detailed: `+++ exited with 0 +++` .

Comment: Ok, I just installed the last binwalk release that officially supports Python 2 (v2.2.1), it works.